# Packet not forwarding

Tags: contiki

There is three nodes A,B,C. A could transmit the packet to C directly according to the routing table. However, I want to transmit the packet to B and then B transmits the packet to C. So I use the function `uip_ds6_route_add` to add the new routing in sniffer `input_packet`. And then use the `uip_ds6_route_rm` to delete the new routing in sniffer `output_packet`. I have succeed to transmit packet from A to B. But when B transmits packet to C, the sniffer shows that B does not forward. Can you give me some instructions to solve this problem

Comment: Firstly,I should apologize for the previous question I have asked which has been closed. I do not have any malicious purpose and I just want to do some detection to protect the safety of IoT